# Chrome stuck at 100% CPU after closing windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, cpu-usage

When doing web development I sometimes hear the fans start making noise and find the Google Chrome process stuck at 100% CPU when checking `top`. This kills my battery life.

The internal Process Monitor shows no tab using the CPU, it's the main thread. A weird thing is that even closing all visible windows will not kill the process, so I have to kill it from the command line.

Since this doesn't seem related to one specific page, I would guess it's related to either some internals (in Dev Tools, likely) or some extension. In the latter case I could disable some extensions and see if I could spot a difference. But is there some other way of finding what the hell it is actually doing? Attaching a debugger seems somewhat overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this after being able to reproduce this using an incognito mode browser session. I was able to deduct that it was related to the checkouts I made in Git, and this is one of the few settings that transfer from the normal session over to incognito mode.

After going to the Sources tab in Dev Tools, removing the source directory, the cpu usage kept normal, even after switching branches. So basically this comes down to some bug in the file watcher functionality inside of Chrome, as it never slows down, no matter how much time it was given.